# Can AD LDS have its own password policies apart from the system its on?

Tags: active-directory, adlds

We just started using AD LDS for membership services to our website, but it looks as though it relies on the password policy of the system it's on. I don't want to relax the password policy for the machine its own but I don't want a password policy for AD LDS. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot - you need to rely on the local machine's policy.